# Roles.GetRolesForUser throws exception Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nullreferenceexception, roles

I have an ASP.NET application that uses the `Roles.GetRolesForUser` method. The call work fines within the application, but when i use the same call in a referenced library, it throws an exception. The exception message is:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

The strange things is that when i check Roles, it is instantiated.

My code looks like this:

```
var roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(userName);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Ok apparently if you calling Roles.GetRolesForUser in a referenced library, you have to use it as follows: var Roles = Roles.Provider.GetRolesForUser(userName); Notice the difference, explicitly calling the Provider on Roles

Comment: Add this as an answer and mark it as accepted, so another user looking for this finds it easier.

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: @JohnSaunders You are right, but this is very exceptional status, which the exception here is .NET Bug

Answer (score 6):

**NOTE: according to the OP's comment himself, this answer solved his problem.**

This is a [.NET Framework bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/967133/roles-getrolesforuser-throw-a-nullreferenceexception-in-a-wcf-service-which-is-hosted-in-asp-net-with-the-aspnetcompatibilityenabled-define-to-false).
To solve this issue call:

```
string[] roles = Roles.Provider.GetRolesForUser(userName);
```

here is a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631032).

Comment: The cause for me was that MSDTC was not running.  The above fix got the code working even when MSDTC was still off.

Answer (score 0):

In MVC 5 you can get user roles with `GetRoles(Id)` method. 
 But, before use `GetRoles` you have to make `userManager` object:

```
var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));

var d = userManager.GetRoles(5);
```